# Nginx - Wrong redirect?

Tags: redirect, nginx, http-status-code-404, config, lets-encrypt

i am using Nginx as Webserver togheter with LetsEncrypt to encrypt my connections.
My homepage have multiple sub-domains, like www.domain.com, mail.domain.com, etc.
Now i want to redirect all "/.well-known" connections to a special root-folder.

I think i have the correct config, but the result isn't what i want.

Here my configs:

**default.vhost**

```
#=============================================
#== Server
#==============================================

server {

        #=============================================
        #== General
        #=============================================

        # Port
        listen 80;

        # Server name
        #server_name _;

        #=============================================
        #== Locations
        #=============================================

        location /.well-known {
                #default_type "text/plain";
                root /var/wwww/LetsEncrypt;
        }

        location / {
                return 301 https://www.example.com$request_uri;
        }
}


server {

        #=============================================
        #== General
        #=============================================

        # Port
        listen 443 ssl;

        # Server name
        #server_name _;

        #=============================================
        #== Locations
        #=============================================

        location / {
                return 301 https://www.example.com$request_uri;
        }
}
```

**www.domain.com**

```
#=============================================
#== HTTP-Server
#=============================================

server {

        #=============================================
        #== General
        #=============================================

        # Port
        listen 443 ssl default_server;

        # Server name
        server_name www.example.com;

        # Root folder
        root /var/www/www.example.com/web/;

        # Order of index files
        index index.php index.html index.htm;

        #=============================================
        #== Includes
        #=============================================

        # SSL configuration
        include /etc/nginx/ssl.conf;

        # PHP configuration
        include /etc/nginx/php.conf;

        #=============================================
        #== Locations
        #=============================================

        location /.well-known/acme-challenge {
                #default_type "text/plain";
                root /var/wwww/LetsEncrypt;
        }

        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }

        location ~ /\.ht {
                deny all;
        }
}
```

**mail.domain.com**

```
#=============================================
#== HTTP-Server
#=============================================

server {

        #=============================================
        #== General
        #=============================================

        # Port
        listen 443 ssl;

        # Server name
        server_name mail.example.com;

        # Root folder
        root /var/www/mail.example.com/web/;

        # Order of index files
        index index.php index.html index.htm;

        #=============================================
        #== Includes
        #=============================================

        # SSL configuration
        include /etc/nginx/ssl.conf;

        # PHP configuration
        include /etc/nginx/php.conf;

        #=============================================
        #== Locations
        #=============================================

        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }

        location ~ /\.ht {
                deny all;
        }
}
```

So, what happens.. mail.domain.com and www.domain.com works great.
Problem is the .well-known rule. Nginx is ignoring it, i always get redirected, instead of getting files from "/var/www/LetsEncrypt".

I thought that the default_server is the problem, but after moving it to "default.vhost" nothing is working (always  404.. what also sound a bit strange...).

I hope you guys could help me :(

Kind regard,
Andreas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly you'll want to use the [nginx 'location begins with' modifier `^~`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) which will capture all requests beginning with the directory specified.

```
location ^~ /.well-known/acme-challenge {
```

Secondly you have `/var/wwww/LetsEncrypt` (4 w's) rather than `/var/www/LetsEncrypt`.

Your location block should look like this:

```
location ^~ /.well-known/acme-challenge {
    #default_type "text/plain";
    root /var/www/LetsEncrypt;
}
```

Also be aware of the difference between [alias](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#alias) and root as root will append the uri to the path, e.g.:

```
alias /var/www/LetsEncrypt; # Will serve files from /var/www/LetsEncrypt

root /var/www/LetsEncrypt; # Will serve files from /var/www/LetsEncrypt/.well-known/acme-challenge
```

This might trip you up if you're trying to serve up a specific directory.

Comment: Okay, I will try it later.
Thanks for the fast reply :)

Comment: So, i have tested the changes and it works perfect! Only "alias" instead of "root" didn't worked But its no big problem. I will set your answer as accepted answer!